# How do I make my areas shaded when I click on them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

How do I make my areas shaded when I click on them?

## Contractor Form (Package One)

```
<area id="39" name ="39" alt="" title="39" href="#" shape="poly" coords="12,204,12,120,138,117,144,72,248,72,252,124,526,125,632,81,668,157,698,149,722,221,658,249,546,197,542,171,106,171,106,209,12,207,546,203" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"000000","strokeWidth":1,"fillColor":"ffffff","fillOpacity":0.6}'/>
<area id="26-3" name ="26-3" alt="" title="26-3" href="#" shape="poly" coords="14,302,12,208,168,208,170,304" />
<area id="26-2" name ="26-2" alt="" title="26-2" href="#" shape="poly" coords="172,304,172,208,238,210,238,306" />
<area id="38A" name ="38A" alt="" title="38A" href="#" shape="poly" coords="530,208,548,172,108,173,110,212" />
<area id="26-1" name ="26-1" alt="" title="26-1" href="#" shape="poly" coords="238,307,238,209,530,208,522,231,498,233,496,294,366,271,308,271,308,305" />
<area id="25" name ="25" alt="" title="25" href="#" shape="poly" coords="310,304,306,272,366,270,508,296,510,348,356,352" />
<area id="24b" name ="24b" alt="" title="24b" href="#" shape="poly" coords="536,196,664,251,646,259,660,267,680,279,690,304,694,316,578,373,576,592,512,615,510,296,496,293,502,232,522,232" />
<area id="24a" name ="24a" alt="" title="24a" href="#" shape="poly" coords="692,314,730,537,578,592,576,373" />
<area id="37" name ="37" alt="" title="37" href="#" shape="poly" coords="354,356,508,350,508,532,494,555,482,567,472,579,462,586,442,597,426,605,410,607,392,609,380,612,378,616,182,616,182,552,354,548" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin to do it. For example, [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Highlighting-Image-Map-Maphilight.html).

Comment: the plugin also show me how to make it shaded when hover over. i need to shade it when I click on it :/